# MUI DataGrid - styling the Exported excel file + making hierarchic dropdown

Tags: reactjs, excel, material-ui, datagrid, dropdown

I have two issues that I trying to solve.

1. first, I want to style my exported excel file with this parameters:

- I want to make long text wrapped in one cell and disable the overflow wrapping format.
  [the first example is what I want to get and second is what I already have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiX5L.png)
- I want to change the background color of the table.
- I want to make the titles of columns bolder then the table values.

I'm using MUI GridToolbarExport component. here is the code of the component of the toolbar for the datagrid.

```
const TreatmentsToolbarForEvent = ({event, usersFromOpen, setUsersFromOpen}: IProps) =>(
        <GridToolbarContainer>
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <GridToolbarColumnsButton sx={{"& .MuiButton-startIcon": {marginLeft: "5px"}}}/>
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <GridToolbarFilterButton sx={{"& .MuiButton-startIcon": {marginLeft: "5px"}}}/>
            <GridToolbarExport sx={{"& .MuiButton-startIcon": {marginLeft: "5px"}}}/>
            <AddFormDialog entity={"treatments"} eventId={event.id}/>
            <FormDialogUsers event={event} open={usersFromOpen} setOpen={setUsersFromOpen}/>
        </GridToolbarContainer>
    );
```

2. second, I want to make hierarchic selection in the datagrid selection and editable columns. [Here is an example from webStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S9Na.png). And [here it how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n03Xu.png).
   Here is the code of the columns of the dataGrid:

```
const departmentSelectDropDown = () => window.config.frontend.departmentOptions;

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        { field: 'department', headerName: strings().department, flex: 1, editable:isInSpecificEvent, type: "singleSelect", valueOptions: departmentSelectDropDown, renderCell: (params) => params.row.department},
        { field: 'system_id', headerName: strings().system_name, flex: 1, editable:isInSpecificEvent, type: "singleSelect", valueOptions: systemsForSelectDropdown, renderCell: (params) => params.row.system_name},
....
```

I hope that we will find the answer together. I will keep searching for the solution and if I will find the solution I will post here.

thanks ahead!! (:

for the styling, I tried to search in MUI documentation and I didn't find something that styles the excel File.
And for the dropdown, I tried to check on MUI DataGrid columns API if I can make hierarchic dropdown and i didnt find solution. i just found grouping dropdown and its not what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For wrapping text in specific column:

There is `columnStyles`, second property in [MUI docks](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-excel-export-options/)

Then you can set your column like this:

```
columnsStyles: {
            <columnNameThatYouWantTextToBeWrapped>: {  <- Here you need to write your column name, or column.field property
                alignment: {
                    wrapText: true
                }
            }
        }
```